# VSTS Web Api gives 403 unauthoratative response

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have created a native app in Azure using App Registration and added required permissions for VSTS Agent

Now, I am able to login using oauth authentication with "ADAL" and able to get the token but when trying to access the web api request it gives Http 403 Response

Here is the code example below

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(vstsCollectionUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));               
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect", "Suppress");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;

            HttpResponseMessage res = client.GetAsync(webapiURL).Result;
        }
```

Please let me know what i am missing

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `authHeader`?

Comment: authHeader is an instance of AuthenticationHeaderValue
authHeader consists oauth Token and passing it as Authorization parameter of HttpClient

Comment: @Shyam Seems it's an authentication issue, Just check the value of `authHeader`, reference below samples for troubleshooing: **Sample 1**- [auth-samples here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/blob/master/DeviceProfileSample/Program.cs) ; **Sample 2** - [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=vsts#rest-api)

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I have tried the Sample 1 and it worked for me thanks.

Actually what exactly I did was, Registered a new app using azure app registration and gave required permissions as VSTS.

After followning the sample I am able to access the rest api for VSTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's an authentication issue, Just check the value of `authHeader`.

You can reference below samples for the authentication with header:

Sample 1- [auth-samples here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-auth-samples/blob/master/DeviceProfileSample/Program.cs) ;

Sample 2 - [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/rest/samples?view=vsts#rest-api)

Post the auth sample as reference here:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace DeviceProfileSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        //============= Config [Edit these with your settings] =====================
        internal const string vstsCollectionUrl = "https://myaccount.visualstudio.com"; //change to the URL of your VSTS account; NOTE: This must use HTTPS
        internal const string clientId = "872cd9fa-d31f-45e0-9eab-6e460a02d1f1";        //update this with your Application ID from step 2.6 (do not change this if you have an MSA backed account)
        //==========================================================================

        internal const string VSTSResourceId = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"; //Static value to target VSTS. Do not change


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AuthenticationContext ctx = GetAuthenticationContext(null);
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            try
            {
                DeviceCodeResult codeResult = ctx.AcquireDeviceCodeAsync(VSTSResourceId, clientId).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("You need to sign in.");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + codeResult.Message + "\n");
                result = ctx.AcquireTokenByDeviceCodeAsync(codeResult).Result;

                var bearerAuthHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                ListProjects(bearerAuthHeader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message + "\n");
            }
        }

        private static AuthenticationContext GetAuthenticationContext(string tenant)
        {
            AuthenticationContext ctx = null;
            if (tenant != null)
                ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);
            else
            {
                ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common");
                if (ctx.TokenCache.Count > 0)
                {
                    string homeTenant = ctx.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().TenantId;
                    ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + homeTenant);
                }
            }

            return ctx;
        }

        private static void ListProjects(AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader)
        {
            // use the httpclient
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(vstsCollectionUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "VstsRestApiSamples");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect", "Suppress");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader;

                // connect to the REST endpoint            
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("_apis/projects?stateFilter=All&api-version=2.2").Result;

                // check to see if we have a succesfull respond
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tSuccesful REST call");
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing what authentication,

```
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", token)));
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(vstsCollectionUrl);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new              
System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials)
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

I hope this helps.